# How to pass AzureCLI credential to docker run (to be used by DefaultAzureCredential inside the container)?

Tags: python-3.x, containers, azure-pipelines, azure-cli2

I am new to Azure Pipeline, and trying to create a job to create Azure ML resources.
Because the CI pipeline runs in a self-hosted agent, and can't run the pipeline in a container, I have to call `docker run` command in AzureCLI@2 task. something like:

```
pool:
  name: 'self-hosted-agent'

stages:
- stage: 'CI'
  jobs:
  - job: create_ml_resources
    steps:
    - task: AzureCLI@2
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: '$(WORKSPACE_SVC_CONNECTION)'
        scriptType: 'bash'
        scriptLocation: inlineScript
        workingDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
        inlineScript: |
          set -e # fail on error
          docker run -e SUBSCRIPTION_ID --rm -t -v "$PWD":/usr/src -w /usr/src $(DOCKER_IMAGE) python -m python.script.to.build_resources
```

and build_resources.py script is like:

```
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.ai.ml import MLClient

ml_client = MLClient(
    DefaultAzureCredential(), subscription_id, resource_group, workspace
)
```

**Problem:
**
The problem is that I need to authenticate to ARM from within the container, so DefaultAzureCredential() can use the credential. But I dont know how to pass the credential from the pipeline job environment to the container!

Can someone shed light on how this credential can be passed to the container run?

**What I have tried so far:
**

1. On my localhost I can fix this by running the container with `-v ~/.azure:/root/azure`, so credential, acquired by "az login", will available inside the container. But in Azure pipeline there isn't such AccessToken in `~/.azure`!
2. I also try exporting `System.AccessTone` as a environment variable, something like:

```
docker run -e SUBSCRIPTION_ID -e SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN=$(System.AccessToken)  --rm -t -v "$PWD":/usr/src -w /usr/src $(DOCKER_IMAGE) bash -c 'az account list'
```

But no luck!

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-identity/azure.identity.environmentcredential?view=azure-python) - you can configure the DefaultAzureCredential with environment variables.

You can set the `AZURE_CLIENT_ID` and `AZURE_TENANT_ID` as parameters or standard variables in the pipeline. The `AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET` should be stored somewhere more secure, either within a variable group or in an azure key vault. Assuming your Azure Service Connection has the correct permissions you can access the secrets from within your azure cli task like

```
clientSecret = az keyvault secret show --name my-client-secret --vault-name my-vault
```